# How can I get the range inside specifc range while working with Worksheet ranges of excel using C# Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, com, excel-interop

I am interacting with Excel worksheet for writing report related data. For this I have to Parse alot of ranges inside each worksheet.

I would like to parse given range and all of it's child ranges should be returned automatically. Unfortunately I can't specify "concreate" range by using Range.Find('concreteRange'...).

I would like to write generic logic for parsing parent ranges and all it's child ranges can be processed further. Otherwise, I would have to parse each child range specifically for each and every parent range.

I am using Excel.Interop library for parsing NamedRanges in a specific Worksheet.

Can any body assist me? Because in this way , my code would much generic and maintainable.

**Edit**

I have different sections ( These are tables ). These tables further contains multiple columns and each column has it's own fomrula and thus should be provided different data from database). For this reason I have logical Parent->Child range relationship.

SO i need somehow..

weightRange = Worksheet_get_range("weightSection");
weightRange.Child.....Or weightRange.ChildRanges ( which should have all columns ranges)

Regards
Usman

Comment: How are you defining a 'child range'?

Comment: No, I am not defining chil range. Look on edit.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? You need to identify location of the 'child range' inside of the 'parent range' on the fly (ie, you need to locate 'weightSection')? Or you know the location of the 'child range' (weightSection is always column D), but you need to access the specific child range once you hold 'parent range' in memory?

Comment: I already defined child ranges inside some parent range
( e.g Parent : A1-->C10 ) and also i set up few child ranges ( i.e A1->A10, B1->B10, C1->C10 ) inside this single parent. Now all I want inside the code, I should be able to select explicitly the parent get_range("A1-C10")

and then using this parent range for getting all it's children ( A1-A10,B1-B10,....) so that my logic for populating the data inside these children can be generalized. Hope you got what I mean. Let me know if this is possible somehow!

Comment: You can try with range Areas property, but I am not sure is going to work (or may be only on disjoint sub-ranges).
Another thing would be to operate with rectangles in your program, converting all range coordinates to points... very hard.